# Slick 2.x filter by mapped column type (java.util.Date)

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

I'm using java.util.Date in my model case class. Since Slick doesn't support j.u.Date out of the box, I added implicit mapping like so `implicit val dateColumnMapper = MappedColumnType.base[Date, SqlDate](d => new SqlDate(d.getTime), d => d)` to my Table class.

But now I'm stuck with filtering by date field: `proposalsQuery.filter(_.since >= since)`. I tried different options but always get compilation errors: `value >= is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[java.util.Date]`

Since, I'm new in Scala/Slick working examples with simple explanation of the problem would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

implicit mapper MUST be available at the place where you write your filter query.

Comment: For question and answer +2.I've moved to my controller my implicit mapper and imported `import java.util.Date`. It works perfectly. Thanks. `implicit val date2SqlDate = MappedColumnType.base[Date, java.sql.Timestamp](
  d => new java.sql.Timestamp(d.getTime),
  d => new java.util.Date(d.getTime)
 )`

Answer (score 0):

you should import this in your file

`import com.github.tototoshi.slick.JdbcJodaSupport._`

and this is the library
`"com.github.tototoshi" %%  "slick-joda-mapper" % "1.2.0"`